# El archivo con modulo argparse no recopila a abrirlo con import

Tags: python, python-3.7, argparse

El archivo con modulo argparse que esta formulado de la siguiente forma:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Paso de parametros")
parser.add_argument("-p1", dest="param1", help="parameter1")
parser.add_argument("-p2", dest="param2", help="parameter2")
params = parser.parse_args()
print(params.param1)
print(params.param2)
```

No lo puedo abrir con este otro archivo python que esta formulado de la siguiente forma:

```
python paso_parametros.py -p1 "parametro1" -p2 "parametro2"
```

Según el libro que estoy leyendo debería imprimirme el siguiente resultado:

parametro1
parametro2

Pero me sale un error en la recopilación de archivo cuando abro el segundo código, alguien podría ayudarme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer código ejecuta perfectamente desde la consola, poniendo el segundo código como instrucción.

> ...este otro archivo python que esta formulado de la siguiente forma

El segundo código no es Python. Si estás en Windows, parece archivo **cmd**. Si es así, le agregas un `pause` al final para que no se cierre y lo guardas con extensión cmd (en la misma ruta de `paso_parametros.py`), funciona bien.

*ejemplo.cmd*

```cmd
@echo off
python paso_parametros.py -p1 "parametro1" -p2 "parametro2"
pause
```